# Close Error Window Automatically on Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm running a Python script that loops through different excel files, and each of these files runs some macros. Some of these files are incomplete, so I get an Excel error like: ![image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbqu9.png)

I want to automatically enter the acknowledge (only one option: ![image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJTOW.png) )
I am using xlwings, so I tried to use display_alerts, both on the app and on the file:

```
app = xw.App(visible=False)
app.display_alerts = False
wb = app.books.open(copy_file)
wb.DisplayAlerts = False
```

The alert keeps popping up. Any advice?

Comment: You should be able to catch the error on the python side with `try/except`. You won't have the error raised and Excel will not show it in a pop up.

Comment: I don't want to catch the error with Python, because it's only one step in the Excel macro that is failing. I don't want to interrupt the execution of the macro.

Comment: The error you're seeing is a Python error (even though you see it through an Excel pop-up) which is why you have to handle it on the Python side.

Comment: You are right. The problem is that it's a Python error raised from a script that is called by the Excel macro. I don't have access to that script. Do you know if there is any way around it?